Excel Formula Condense and Simplify
I'd like to condense and simplify this formula into one line, so as to drop the E1-half-step, without getting too redundant. This is one of the first steps I'll use to tie work orders together and streamline my paperwork process.
A1 [Serial Number(pivot point, not referenced)] = static input(????????????????????)
B1 (Work Order) = static input(#######)
C1 (Date) = static input(dd/mm/yyyy)
D1 (Technician Name) = static input(LAST, FIRST M)
E1 [Reformat Name(LAST, FIRST M to LAST, FIRST)]
=IF(LEN(D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D1," ",""))<2,D1,LEFT(D1,FIND(" ",D1,FIND(" ",D1)+1)))
F1 (Disposition) = static input(restock, repair, liquidate, etc.)
G1 (Findings) = static input(no issue, self-resolve, broken part, unfit for use, etc.)
H1 {Output[Work Order History(Reformats Date and Name)]}
="Previously worked "&B1&" on "&TEXT(C1,"DD")&UPPER(TEXT(C1,"MMM"))&YEAR(C1)&" by "&PROPER(RIGHT(E1,LEN(E1)-FIND(", ",E1)))&" "&LEFT(LEFT(E1,FIND(", ",E1)-1),1)&". -- "&F1&"; "&G1
Output: Previously worked 0000001 on 01JAN2024 by John S. -- restock, no issue.
Feel free to rephrase or add other variables, if you feel this summary might be missing anything. Thanks!

which formula? ... you posted many

One way to simplify the H1 (eventual) formula without the need of repeating the E1 logic multiple times in it, would be to define a named range or named formula in Excel.
1. Create a Named Formula:

Go to the Formulas tab
Click on Name Manager
Click on New
In the Name field, enter a name, e.g., ReformattedName.
In the Refers to field, enter the formula that you currently have in E1: =IF(LEN(D1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D1," ",""))<2,D1,LEFT(D1,FIND(" ",D1,FIND(" ",D1)+1)))
Click OK

2. Use the Named Formula in H1:
Now, instead of repeating the formula in H1, you can reference the named formula. Your H1 formula would look like this: ="Previously worked "&B1&" on "&TEXT(C1,"DD")&UPPER(TEXT(C1,"MMM"))&YEAR(C1)&" by"&PROPER(RIGHT(ReformattedName,LEN(ReformattedName)-FIND(", ",ReformattedName)))&LEFT(LEFT(ReformattedName,FIND(",",ReformattedName)-1),1)&". -- "&F1&"; "&G1

But to be honest you can further simplify the formula, also the date part of it, and no need for the long E1 formula at all:
Try this:
="Previously worked "&B1&" on "&UPPER(TEXT(C1,"DDMMMYYYY")&" by "&PROPER(MID(D1,FIND(", ",D1)+2,FIND(" ",D1,FIND(", ",D1)+2)-FIND(", ",D1)-2))&" "&LEFT(D1,1)&". -- "&F1&"; "&G1)

You can even condense the TEXT(C1) date part with UPPER(TEXT(c1,"dd mmm yyyy")

without the spaces though. I added it

If you have 365:
=LET(
    _name, PROPER(LET(n, TEXTSPLIT(D2, , {",", " "}), INDEX(n, 3) & " " & LEFT(INDEX(n, 1))) & "."),
    _date, UPPER(TEXT(C2, "ddmmmyyyy")),
    TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, "Previously worked", B2, "on", _date, "by", _name, "--", F2 & ";", G2)
)

